Pulling a shuffled list index returns the value of the original index
I'm attempting a silly little "random" number generator to try to get to grips with how lists and pulling values from them works in python.
I have a variable defined as x, and I ask the code to pull a value from the list at the index of x.
After shuffling the list and asking it to pull the value from index x, it pulls the value from the original list instead of the newly shuffled list.
I'm certain I'm missing something fairly obvious about how the list is shuffled. I originally assumed it's because it's generating a new list upon shuffling instead of actually modifying the original list. However, when printing the original value for list it does show it as the shuffled list and not the original, meaning the original list has actually been modified unless I'm mistaken. I am having a heck of a time troubleshooting this.
import random
numbers = [2, 1, 3, 1, 2]
x = 2 # I plan to import x from a dict with various values 

get_shuffled_number = numbers[x]
print(numbers)
print(get_shuffled_number) #shows the value expected upon print
random.shuffle(numbers) 
print(numbers) #shows the shuffled list
print(get_shuffled_number) #this pulls the original value from the list at index (x) before being shuffled

gets the output
[2, 1, 3, 1, 2]
3
[1, 2, 2, 3, 1]
3

so numbers[x] is pulling the index of 2 from the original list and not the shuffled list after being shuffled.

You never redefined get_shuffled_number so why do you expect it to be different?

Code review time.
numbers = [2, 1, 3, 1, 2]
x = 2

Ok, good.
(I might have opted for index i = 2, but fine, whatever, LGTM.)
get_shuffled_number = numbers[x]

This is just Wrong.
We choose a verb when naming a def get_shuffled_number(...): function,
and we choose a noun for such an assignment.
So prefer to assign shuffled_number = ....
Choosing the wrong name affects how you and your colleagues
reason about the code.
And not in a good way.
What you wanted to do was

shuffle
extract the x-th element
shuffle again
extract the x-th element again

But you didn't do that.
You assigned the variable exactly once,
before the shuffle,
so understandably it never changed thereafter.

As a separate item, you chose three distinct values
for a 5-element list.
Prefer to populate that list with five distinct values.
Even then, please understand that after a shuffle()
you would still have a 20% chance of the selected
number being unchanged.
Use a longer list of distinct values
if you wish to reduce that likelihood.

get_shuffled_number = numbers[x]

It seems that you expect this statement to establish a permanent formula; that get_shuffled_number shall always be equal to the third element of numbers, even if the contents of numbers changes.
No.  It doesn't work like that.  The assignment is performed once, and that's the end of it.  There is no ongoing relationship between get_shuffled_number and numbers.
(Excel does work like that, though.  Have you done a lot of work with Excel?)

I do have experience with spreadsheets and metric reporting from sales manager positions over the years. It's definitely affecting the way I approach problems as I learn python. Thank you for the feedback

The line get_shuffled_number = numbers[x] doesn't do what you're looking for. You seem to expect your print statement to see "get_shuffled_number," then go back and find numbers[x].
However, get_shuffled_number doesn't represent a process; it represents a value. In this case, when you first initialize it, the interpreter immediately looks into numbers[x], pulls out the number 3, and puts that number into the variable.
In other words, get_shuffled_number doesn't mean "whatever is at the x'th index of the list." It means "whatever was at the x'th index of the list."
What you want to do instead is re-access numbers after you shuffled the list, without referring to get_shuffled_number. This code sample might help you understand the differences between the two approaches. (Of course, the numbers will be different.)
import random
numbers = [2, 1, 3, 1, 2]
x = 2 # I plan to import x from a dict with various values 

get_shuffled_number = numbers[x]
print(numbers)
print(get_shuffled_number) # Prints 3 in your example
random.shuffle(numbers) 

print(numbers) # Prints the list in its entirety

print(get_shuffled_number) # Prints 3 again, since g_s_n remembers what 
                           # it was set to first
print(numbers[x]) # Prints 2 in your example, since you're getting the
                  # current value instead of what you initially stored.

